# Health check in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

Does anyone know how I can tell my cloud foundry instance to monitor my health endpoint, so that when my health endpoint says that the app health is not status: UP, that the app is restarted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cf CLI 6.24.0 (released Feb 2017) exposed this type of health checking.
In your app manifest, use:

```
applications:
- name: myapp
  health-check-type: http
  health-check-http-endpoint: /admin/health
```

Your app needs to return a 200 status code from that path, or an error code when it's not status UP.

You can also use the [`cf set-health-check`](http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/set-health-check.html) command to configure it on existing apps.

Check out [this documentation](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/healthchecks.html) for more details on the different health check types.

Comment: If using Spring actuator, I'm not sure `health` actuator returns non-200 http code in case the app isn't healthy and PCF health check relies on the error code. Do you know if that works?

Answer (score 0):

If an app instance dies, Cloud Foundry, by default, will new up a new instance and try to start it. That resiliency is built into Cloud Foundry.

Actuators are rest end points auto injected in your app that allow you to see the app's status and health at runtime. 
 https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/

Try Actuators out.

Comment: Actuators do not help the situation that I am talking about. The actuator health endpoint could indicate a status of other than "UP". Cloud foundry doesn't watch that endpoint. It has it's own internal health check. I was specifically asking if there was a way with either a user defined property, or a setting in the manifest file to tell it to call my health endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that custom url health checking is available to day in CF.  If your application instance is no longer healthy and you want to restart it you can System.exit(1) and CF will restart it for you.

I've heard rumors of custom health checks possibly coming in the future with the CC V3 api and Diego.

Comment: Thanks. That means that I have to have a polling mechanism to check my health endpoint then call System.exit. Obviously not an optimal solution. I'm actually suprised that they haven't added something like that a long time ago. Something like:

application:
   health-endpoint: /admin/health
   health-response-contains: "status":"UP"

Answer (score 0):

the way to do health check in PCF

`cf set-health-check APP-NAME <HEALTH-CHECK-TYPE> --endpoint <CUSTOM-HTTP-ENDPOINT>`

HEALTH-CHECK-TYPE = process | port | http ( ideally http for web apps )

CUSTOM-HTTP-ENDPOINT = /health

Reference: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/healthchecks.html